# Xcode 6.3 - shell script invocation error (Parse Crash Reporting)

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I recently got an error when I turn off the internet connection and build my project. When I turn the internet back on the error dissapears and the build is successful.

[image: ERROR Xcode 6.3]

I have the following shall script when using Parse Crash Reporting:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
cd <path_to_cloudcode_folder>

parse symbols -p "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because I didnt have a default app after parse new because it wouldnt accept my password.

1. `curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | sudo /bin/bash`
2. `parse new` (delete exsisting parse folder if any)
3. enter your email / password
4. then you will be prompted to choose the app you are working on by typing the # and enter on the terminal